# VB Net Class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have generated an entity framework database first class as a class library in VB.Net. Works fine with several other projects. How do I use it in a C# project? I've made a reference to the dll, and tried using GCDataLayer; and GCDataLayer.GCDataLayer where that is both the assembly name and the root namespace, neither works. Error asks if I've forgotten an assembly or reference.

Comment: If you have added the reference then make sure you are specifying the correct namespaces. It should work.

Comment: Are the types `Public` in the generated EF classes?

Comment: My problem seems to be that I am not using the right namespace. What would it be?

Comment: how do we not what the name space is.. can you tell us ?

Comment: Yes. They are generated as Partial Public Class classname.

Comment: Should work fine; without seeing some code its impossible to help.

Comment: Both the assembly name and the namespace name listed on the properties page show GCDataLayer, which is the project name. When using these in a VB project I just Import GCDataLayer.

Comment: show your code and stop beating around the bush / wasting time.. it's not top secret code especially if it's not even working

Comment: Then create the most simple assembly with the most simple HelloWorld class, compile the DLL and try importing that one. If it works, there's a typo in your GCDataLayer thing or a typo in the referencing...

Comment: @user2250708 The reason your question was downvoted and closed is that you didn't provide us with enough information to solve your problem.  The commenters have said as much.  If you want your questions to be better received, then you should provide the information needed to solve the problem. In this case, a minimal example the reproduces the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make sure you've added the reference, as well as set the types you're trying to access to public. Once this is done, you should make `using` references where appropriate, otherwise you'll need to specify the entire namespace address each time you reference it.

See [Namespaces in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx) and look over the code you generated to figure out what those Namespace names are.